# ASP.NET dynamically created textbox doesn't change value

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, webforms

I have the following issue: 
I create a TextBox dynamically in my web page, its value is "initialVal" in the beginning.
Now I need to make a postback (not callback) to the server, and during this operation, I need to compute/change the value of my textbox to other value.

Here's an example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
        txtBox.ID = "newButton";
        form1.Controls.Add(txtBox);
        txtBox.Text = "initialVal";

        if (IsPostBack && Session["change"] == null)
        {
            txtBox.Text = "change";
            Session["change"] = true;
        }
    }
```

The problem: even if I change the value via code, the textbox will keep the text "initialVal". I feel this is something related to the view state, but I don't understand.
Coudl anyone please help me here?

Thanks.

Comment: Better if you create it in Init event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you load the page it is running this:

```
txtBox.Text = "initialVal";
```

You should wrap this in a check for postback:

```
if (!Page.IsPostback)
{
    txtBox.Text = "initialVal";
}
```

That said, `onLoad` is the wrong event to do the creation, for it to be valid in the early enough in the page lifecycle, use `OnInit`.
See this [article on MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317794).

---

Here is the final code from @user2890888:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page 
{ 
  TextBox txtBox = null; 

  protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  { 
    txtBox = new TextBox(); 
    txtBox.ID = "newButton"; 
    form1.Controls.Add(txtBox); 
  } 

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  { 
     if (!IsPostBack) 
     { 
       txtBox.Text = "initialVal"; 
     } 

     if (IsPostBack && Session["change"] == null) 
     { 
       txtBox.Text = "change"; 
       Session["change"] = true; 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: thanks Nikolai, I will put the solution in the Question body.

Comment: @user2890888 I'll edit the answer and add it in so it is readable, if thats ok.

Answer (score 1):

Create your dynamic textbox creation in !IsPostBack

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
if(!isPostBack){
            TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
            txtBox.ID = "newButton";
            form1.Controls.Add(txtBox);
            txtBox.Text = "initialVal";
    }
            if (IsPostBack && Session["change"] == null)
            {
                txtBox.Text = "change";
                Session["change"] = true;
            }
        }
```

Thanks and let me know if your issue still pending

Comment: nope, first of all the txtBox will become a local variable inside the if, code will not compile. Second, even if I get out of "if" the txtBox, it will be null. The TextBox must be created all the time, no only on !IsPostBack.

Answer (score 0):

Find the **`TextBox`** and use it

```
TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)FindControl("txtBox");
txtBox.Text = "change";
```

Answer (score 0):

Even now you are having issue and your textBox is not  getting the value you needed.
Store your new value for TEXTBOX in a hiddenfield.
I mean ,

```
 if (IsPostBack && Session["change"] == null)
{
   hiddenfield1.value = "change";    
}
```

and later in your page script, you can assign back the value in this hiddenfield1 to textbox.

```
$(document).ready(
{
$('#txtBoxID').value=$('#hiddenfield1').value;
}
);
```